# Why does my second monitor fade in and out every second?

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, hdmi

The monitor is relatively new and hasn't started doing this until I set up dual screens. I have a GTX 770, my main monitor plugged in by DVI and the secondary (fading) monitor by HDMI. The monitor works perfectly fine and presents no issues, but every second is alternates from darker to lighter, maybe just a few shades, but enough to be noticable and annoying.

What could be causing this?

Comment: Is the refresh rate close to the AC mains frequency? If so, try changing rate from 60 Hz to 50 Hz or the other way around.

Comment: Can you provide a video of this? Have you swapped the monitors (DVI <--> HDMI)? It sounds faulty.

Comment: does the second monitor have an auto-black-level feature or anything that might adjust brightness based upon screen content or ambient lighting? Also: check for "adaptive brightness" in the computer power options.